# Angular CLI - Set Up production proxy for now deploying

Tags: angular, rest, angular-cli

I am currently using `now.sh` for deploying my app. Recently, I decided to move the `baseUrl` for requests to a `proxy.config.json` file.

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

For deploying with `now.sh` I change the `scripts` in `package.json` to:

```
"start": "serve dist/ --single",
"build": "ng build --prod",
```

so, first, I did a `ng build`.

The thing is, I'm needing a different `target` for `proxy.config.json`, because I deployed an API and I want to use it in the production app

I was thinking on having two files `proxy.config.dev.json` and `proxy.config.prod.json`, but I don't know if I can target a different proxy with the `cli`. The problem is that I'm using `serve` for production and not `ng serve` so `proxy-config` is not available.

What do you suggest? How can I get to work it?

Answer (score 4):

I have realized that is a better solution to use "environments" which came by default with `angular-cli`.

So I setup a `baseUrl` in both environments `{dev, prod}`. And then the builds will not change. Then you have to modify your services to use this env variable.

Comment: I gather you're using ng serve to serve up your prod environment? From what i've read that's not ideal for production (i won't rehash the reasons here). Mostly it appears you're supposed to run ng build --prod and then take the static assets and serve them in production (so you get minification / uglification / AOT optimization etc.). If you need to realize any of these benefits that you're going to be back to my answer above on exploring tools that have proxy capability. http-server has a simple proxy that may suffice for some. i'm trying nginx for now as that has more  proxy features.

Answer (score 1):

ng serve uses the angular cli which accepts a parameter for a proxy file config (details here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve) . the 'serve' command you're using in production is another package (I assume this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) which doesn't support the same feature set. 
You need to a web server that supports proxying (e.g. nginx appears to as detailed here http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy) OR else a standalone solution for the proxy feature that complements popular http server packages like 'serve', 'http-server', 'lite-server' e.g. some network appliances can help as well. If you / anyone else finds other good options for hosting angular apps w/ a proxy please do share as I'm looking to evaluate more options also.

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular Interceptor and Angular cli way to set baseUrl as explained above and up voted for giving hint. In case someone looking for more info then following helps to move forward

```
`<pre>
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
   HttpInterceptor,
   HttpRequest,
   HttpHeaders,
   HttpHandler,
   HttpEvent,
   HttpEventType
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class WebApiBaseURLInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

   className = "WebApiBaseURLInterceptor";

   constructor() {
       // add more http options here like OAuth2 access token
       const httpOptions = {
           headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
       };
   }

   /**
    *
    * @param {HttpRequest<any>} req
    * @param {HttpHandler} next
    * @returns {Observable<HttpEvent<any>>}
    */
   intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):   
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

//the baseURL set in environment folder which has both Dev and Prod
       const url = environment.baseUrl;
       req = req.clone({
           url: url + req.url
       });
       // return next.handle(req);

       // lets add elapse time difference 
       const started = Date.now();
       return next.handle(req).do(event => {
           if (event.type == HttpEventType.Response) {
               const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
               console.log(`${this.className}: Request for ${req.urlWithParams} took ${elapsed} ms.`);
           }
       });
   }
}
</pre>`
```

Following is Dev environment folder and file so edit as below,

// The file contents for the current environment will overwrite these during build.

// The build system defaults to the dev environment which uses `environment.ts`, but if you do

// `ng build --env=prod` then `environment.prod.ts` will be used instead.

// The list of which env maps to which file can be found in `.angular-cli.json`.

```
`<pre>
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/'
};
</pre>`
```